# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'jira'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jira, python-jira

I try to use JIRA library for Python in aws lambda. I create layer in lambda put in it the zip file that the contain the output of this command :

```
 pip3 install -t /home/reham/projectes/jira/python jira
```

when I run code in lambda i get this error :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: e348111f-e225-4af6-8fc6-8be9cd793464 Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'jira'
```

try to use runtimes python3.6 and python3.7 but not work.

could please anyone help me?

Comment: What is the exact structure of your zip layer?

Comment: the exact structure jira/python